# Coffee Script not fire on page change, but works on page load. [Rails 5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am using coffee script in my rails project, but the problem is it works only when i load(refresh) the page instead when the page renders, it should also work on the page view change.

here is the script i am using:

**facebook.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: env["app_id"], cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `"turbolinks:load"`:

```
ready = ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: env["app_id"], cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true


$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // ...
})
```