# How to make LIKE clause case-insensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using a LIKE clause in Ruby On Rails. When I try to search for records by typing **"more"** it doesn't return anything, but when I do with **"More"**, then it returns the records which contains **More** keyword, so it seems like it behaves in a case-sensitive way.

Is it possible to make this case-insensitive?

Here is the query I am using currently:

```
Job.where('title LIKE ? OR duration LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume you're using Postgres.

You can use [`ILIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)

```
Job.where('title ILIKE ? OR duration ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Or a some tricky hack `lower()`:

```
Job.where('lower(title) LIKE lower(?) OR lower(duration) LIKE lower(?)', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Comment: Ok thanks so much, could you please suggest which one to use?

Comment: `LIKE/ILIKE` prefered because it's cleaner.

Comment: Ok i have another question, posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462428/coffee-script-not-fire-on-page-change-but-works-on-page-load-rails-5
if you know the solution then please answer it there, would be really appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: You can write this a lot more elegantly with a named placeholder instead. `Job.where('title ILIKE :s OR duration ILIKE :s', s: "%#{params[:search]}%")`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
def query_job(query)
  job_query = "%#{query.downcase}%"
  Job.where("lower(title) LIKE ? or lower(duration) LIKE ?", job_query, job_query) 
end 

query_job(params[:search])
```

Comment: [`It is dangerous when you manually do string concatenations to create your query.`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: Note that Зелёный's comment no longer applies since this answer was edited.